# Blender Python Origin Adjustments

Tags: python

I'm new to Python programming in Blender. I have a need to duplicate a series of cubes and slowly rotate them edge to edge. I therefore need their rotation origins to be moved from center, to the edge butted against their neighboring cube.

I've been using:

```
bpy.context.scene.cursor_location = (x,y,z)
```

What I really want are coordinates that simply say, "move the x,y,z to the relative right (or left) of a particular cube. My understanding was that the origin point is relative to its last position, and that I merely needed to calc the difference.

I'm setting the origin AFTER creating the cube that needs it origin moved. My code order is:

- Create cube
- Rotate cube x and z
- Set new origin for final rotation based on radians
- Rotate cube z with differential

I've reviewed several functions for rotation, but not quite in line with what I'm trying here. I need all the x,y,z to match side that needs to rotate. I'm open to better ways. Like I said, this is new to me.

[image: origin point too far left]

Comment: Are you trying to create a concertina. ie a set of hinged tiles?

Comment: I hadn't thought about truly hinging them, but that would probably be a good idea.